# Protocol is not being recognized

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've tried to set up a protocol for some configuration setup, I know that my protocol is not being recognized because I havent set the delegate to self. But here comes my question, I have 2 classes: Manager and Configurator.

Manager class sends the message to the protocol defined by itself. Configurator class adopts the protocol and implements it.

Manager class:

```
@protocol ManagerDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSDictionary *)getString:(NSString *)type;
@end
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ManagerDelegate> delegate;

-(void)someMethod{
 NSSting *test = [self.delegate getString:@"protocol"];
```

Config Class:

```
 @interface Configurator : NSObject <ManagerDelegate>
 .....
```

And in the .m file

```
 - (NSDictionary *)getString:(NSString *)type{
    return type;}
```

I dont want or need to instantiate the Configurator class or the Manager class, or this is totally necessary?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

When your `config` class `alloc`'s the `manager` class, it needs to say `[self.manager setDelegate: self]` otherwise the `manager` class is unaware that the `config` class is it's delegate.
Both classes will need to be instantiated somewhere in order to use any of the methods or protocols defined.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create delegate here.  `- (NSDictionary *)getString:(NSString *)type` is method in `Configurator` class which is subclass of `NSObject`. You can create instance of Configurator class in Manager class and access the methods of Configurator class using this instance.

```
 -(void)someMethod{
Configurator *objConfigurator = [[Configurator alloc] init];//Or You can declare instance in Configurator.h.
 NSSting *test = [objConfigurator getString:@"protocol"];
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: you gave me a hint to solve it. What I did was setting up a singleton instance of configurator class, and on the init method of manager class I set up the delegate to an instance of configurator class. Thanks!